# Como posso descobri qual arquivo inclui o outro no PHP?

Tags: php, include

Gostaria de saber em PHP como faço para poder descobrir qual é o arquivo pai, em uma inclusão, através do arquivo filho.

Exemplo:

- avo.php
- pai.php
- filho.php

No arquivo `avo.php` eu tenho:

```
include_once 'pai.php';
```

E no arquivo `pai.php` eu tenho:

```
#pai.php
include_once 'filho.php';
```

- Através do arquivo `filho.php`, como posso descobrir que ele é incluído por `pai.php`?
- Como posso descobrir, atavés de `filho.php`, que `pai.php` é incluído por `avo.php`?

Comment: Não sei se existe um método nativo que faça isto, mas se você precisa saber quem é o "pai" para fazer algo dinamizado no filho, uma alternativa seria sobrescrever a função include, escrevendo o nome da classe que está realizando o include em uma váriavel, então no filho você tem acesso a essa variável e respectivamente o nome.

Comment: Na verdade, o objetivo é descobrir de onde vem a inclusão. Estou numa aplicação onde uso `filho.php`, porém não sei quem é o arquivo que inclui essa classe. Entende?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) ou [`debug_print_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php), ele pode detectar tanto `include`, `require`, `include_once`, `require_once`, quanto escopo de funções e classes.

## Usando `debug_backtrace()`:

- Arquivo **/foo/a.php**:

  ```
  <?php
  function a_test($str)
  {
      echo "\nOlá: $str";
      var_dump(debug_backtrace());
  }

  a_test('amigo');
  ?>
  ```
- Arquivo **/foo/b.php**:

  ```
  <?php
  include_once '/foo/a.php';
  ?>
  ```
- Resultado:

  ```
  Olá: amigo
  array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
      ["file"] => string(10) "/foo/a.php"
      ["line"] => int(10)
      ["function"] => string(6) "a_test"
      ["args"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0] => &string(6) "amigo"
      }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
      ["file"] => string(10) "/foo/b.php"
      ["line"] => int(2)
      ["args"] =>
      array(1) {
        [0] => string(10) "/foo/a.php"
      }
      ["function"] => string(12) "include_once"
    }
  }
  ```

## Usando `debug_print_backtrace`:

- Arquivo **foo.php**:

  ```
  <?php
  function a() {
      b();
  }

  function b() {
      c();
  }

  function c(){
      debug_print_backtrace();
  }

  a();
  ?>
  ```
- Arquivo **index.php**:

  ```
  <?php
  include 'foo.php';
  ?>
  ```
- Resultado:

  ```
  #0  c() called at [/foo.php:10]
  #1  b() called at [/foo.php:6]
  #2  a() called at [/foo.php:17]
  #3  include(/foo.php) called at [/index.php:3]
  ```

Comment: Só para parecer chato: Vou usar `debug_print_backtrace`, rsrsrs

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Só pra ser outro chato, editei a resposta :)