# Lançar um erro com trigger_error ou Exception em um escopo diferente

Tags: php, exceção

Supondo que eu tenha uma função em um arquivo chamado foo.php:

```
<?php
function foo() {
    trigger_error('Olá mundo!', E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

E no arquivo index.php eu usaria assim:

```
<?php
require 'foo.php';

//Chamando erro
foo();
```

Ele vai emitir um erro mais ou menos assim:

> Fatal error: Olá mundo! in /path/foo.php on line 3

No entanto eu gostaria de emitir o `trigger_error` no arquivo que chamei `foo();`, por exemplo, veja que aparece o caminho `/path/foo.php on line 3`, mas o que eu gostaria de obter é o caminho in `/path/index.php on line 5` pois esta linha é a linha aonde chamei `foo();`.

Sei que posso criar um erro customizado usando `echo` ou `printf` por exemplo, só que o problema é que estes erros customizados não afetam o `error_get_last` e o `error_clear_last`.

Gostaria de saber se é possível definir em um `Exception` por exemplo a linha e o escopo do erro.

Comment: Antes de dar um voto negativo entenda o modelo da comunidade, leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer e http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange e se tiver algum outro motivo pro downvote justifique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei um ótimo exemplo no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9556653/1518921) que permite de certa forma usar informar o qual o escopo que o método customizado foi chamado.

Será necessário usar o `$trace = debug_backtrace(FALSE);` que permite saber aonde o seu método foi chamado.

O foo.php deve ficar algo como:

```
<?php
function foo() {
    //Pega o escopo de quem chamou foo();
    $trace = debug_backtrace(false);

    $message = 'Olá mundo! ' .
        sprintf('in %s on line %d Triggered', $trace[0]['file'], $trace[0]['line']);

    $trace = NULL;

    trigger_error($message, E_USER_NOTICE);
}
```

Ao executar o index.php:

```
<?php
require 'foo.php';

//Chamando
foo();

echo '<pre>';
print_r(error_get_last());
echo '</pre>';
```

Irá ter o erro na tela e ainda poderá usar `error_get_last()` (isto vai variar de qual tipo de erro esta usando no `trigger_error` ou se vai capturar com `set_handler_error`), a saída será algo assim:

> **Notice:** Olá mundo! in /path/index.php on line 5 Triggered in **/path/foo.php** on line **11**
>
> Array
> (
> [type] => 1024
> [message] => Olá mundo! in /path/index.php on line 5 Triggered
> [file] => /path/foo.php
> [line] => 11
> )

Note que no `error_get_last` a linha o arquivo informado são do foo.php, mas você pode fazer um parse no `message` se necessitar.

A ideia de criar um erro customizado assim é poder criar funções próprias e se houver alguma falha o script conseguira informar exatamente aonde foi executado o método, por exemplo:

```
function dividir($a, $b) {
    $err = NULL;

    if (false === is_numeric($a)) {
        $err = 'Primeiro argumento é invalido';
    } else if (false === is_numeric($b)) {
        $err = 'Segundo argumento é invalido';
    } else if ($b == 0) {
        $err = 'Não pode dividir por zero';
    }

    if ($err) {
       $trace = debug_backtrace(false);

       $message = $err .
           sprintf('in %s on line %d Triggered', $trace[0]['file'], $trace[0]['line']);

       $trace = NULL;
       trigger_error($message, E_USER_NOTICE);
       return NULL;
    }

    return $a / $b;
}
```

Neste caso temos 3 possíveis erros, então se usarmos o método assim no index.php:

```
<?php
require 'foo.php';

echo dividir(10, 0);
```

Vamos ter o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Não pode dividir por zero in index.php on line 4 Triggered in foo.php on line 20

Alguns detalhes nesta outra resposta sobre debug_backtrace: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/78168/3635